# C# error: The type or namespace name '' could not be found, checked framework

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, connection

Using Databaselaag doesn't work, i have done all these steps http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8d90a/connect-oledb-database-in-C-Sharp-in-easy-steps/.

I'm trying to connect an MS Acces Database with my windowsformapplication. All the frameworks are on 4 client profile

The type or namespace name 'Databaselaag' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

that is the error im getting, the using Databaselaag; in my second code could not be found be i have no idea why...

Here is my database code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Databaselaag

{

public class DBaccess
{

private static string connectionstr;

static DBaccess()
{
    string mdffile;
    mdffile = @"C:\Users\rik\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Week-2-Opdracht\Database\Clienten.accdb";

    connectionstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + mdffile + "'";


}

public static DataSet Getwaardenquery(string sqlstr)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Console.WriteLine(sqlstr);
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);

    OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, con);
    dap.Fill(ds);
    return ds;

}

public static int Uitvoerenquery(string sqlstr)
{
    int resultaat = -1;
    Console.WriteLine(sqlstr);

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        resultaat = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        string x = exp.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return resultaat;
}

}
```

And this is the Clienten code, i want to link the database with this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Week_2_Opdracht_MODEL;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using Databaselaag;


namespace Week_2_Opdracht_MODEL
 {
 public class Clienten
{
public static List<Client> _clientenlijst = new List<Client>();

public Clienten()
{
    VulClientObjecten();
}

//maak dummy gegevens aan
public static void VulClientObjecten()
{
    Client client;

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        client = new Client(
            /* "Nummer */i,
            "Voornaam",
            "Achternaam",
            /* man/vrouw */true,
            /* leeftijd */25 + (i * 2),
            "Woonplaats");

        _clientenlijst.Add(client);
    }
}

//create
public static void VoegClientToe(Client client)
{
    _clientenlijst.Add(client);
}

//read
public static Client ZoekClient(int clientNummer)
{
    foreach (Client client in _clientenlijst)
    {
        if (client.Nummer == clientNummer)
        {
            return client;
        }
    }
    return new Client();
}

//delete
public static void VerwijderClient(int clientNummer)
{
    Client client = ZoekClient(clientNummer);
    _clientenlijst.Remove(client);
    Console.WriteLine(client);
}

//update
public static void UpdateClient(int clientNummer, string voorNaam, string achterNaam, 
                                bool geslacht, int leefTijd, string woonPlaats)
{
    VerwijderClient(clientNummer);

    Client client = new Client( clientNummer,  voorNaam,  achterNaam, geslacht,  leefTijd,  woonPlaats);

    VoegClientToe(client);


}



public static void VerwijderClient(int clientNummer, string voorNaam, string achterNaam, 
                                    bool geslacht, int leefTijd, string woonPlaats)
{
    Client client = ZoekClient(clientNummer);
    _clientenlijst.Remove(client);
    Console.WriteLine(client);     
}
}
```

Is there someone who knows what's going on?

Comment: Have added the reference of the Databaselaag to the current project that you are working

Comment: Next problem.. I get no more errors, but when i run and add clients, they dont add in my acces database when i open it. I've checked all the rows and collums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `Databaselaag` has reference in your `Week_2_Opdracht_MODEL` project ?

Comment: Next problem.. I get no more errors, but when i run and add clients, they dont add in my acces database when i open it. I've checked all the rows and collums

Comment: Uggh i really suck at this.. thanks, no idea how or where i am going to do it but i know that's the problem

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the reference of the Databaselaag to the current project that you are working